# blocks are not translated in Panels

Tags: blocks, panels, i18n-l10n

I have a simple `panel page` containing 4 blocks that are all translated (and set to translatable). However they are always displayed in English (default language).

The taxonomy term is passed as a context and is used to display the page title. And it is also translated (`%taxonomy_term:i18n-name`)

The rest of the page is translated correctly. I unfortunately don't have much more info to share as this is basically it...

What am I missing here? Thanks for your help!

I am using Drupal 7 and Panels 3

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known Ctools issue](http://drupal.org/node/1168272) - there is a patch at comment #49.